# About the usage of `this` in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just wrote one module like this:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.dashboard').controller('mainControl',mainControl);

    mainControl.$inject = ['whichToShow','authService'];
    function mainControl(whichToShow,authService){
        var self=this;
        this.values=whichToShow.getVar();
        this.logOut=function(){
            whichToShow.setVar(false);
            authService.logOutUser();
        };
        this.removeEvent=function(eventId){
            authService.removeEvent(eventId);
        }

        authService.setOnAuth(authDataCallback);
        // Callback to set user's events.
        function authDataCallback(authData) {
            if (authData) {
                console.log("User is logged in with " + authData.email);
                self.eventList={};
                whichToShow.setVar(true);
            } else {
                console.log("User is logged out");
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

In this module the line `self.eventList={};`, at first I just use `this.eventList={}`, the console tells me `TypeError: Cannot set property 'eventList' of undefined` all the time.

Until I set `self` as `this`, and use `self` in the authDataCallback function. I finally figure it out how to solve it but don't know why is this? Could you tell me?

Comment: can you publish your service please ?

Comment: It has everything to do with scope -- your `authDataCallback()` method gets called from a different scope, so `this` is no longer what you thought it should be. Setting `self = this` before `authDataCallback()` gets called allows you to access the original scope.

Comment: There a million good resources on `this` -- but the first Google search result I found on SO was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

The `this` keyword in JS is context specific. Your callback has it's own execution context so `this` refers to that context and isn't looking in the surrounding context.

Other than assign this to a variable and puling on the variable, you can use `.bind(this)` to use it in the function's context or you start using ES6 fat arrow functions.